# Store options as descriptive strings or numbers?

Tags: php, mysql

What's the best way of storing options in mySQL?  As descriptive strings or integers that are associated with each string.

Let's say I have this question in my UI:

What's your favorite ice cream flavor?

- Vanilla
- Chocolate
- Strawberry

Is it better to store those in the DB as 1, 2, 3 in an INT(1) field or as strings vanilla, chocolate, or strawberry, in a CHAR field?  I know the INT field will be faster, but probably not drastically unless there's tens of thousands of rows.

If they're stored as strings then I wouldn't need to do any extra PHP code, whereas if they're stored as numbers, I'd have to define the value of 1 = vanilla, etc...

What's the general consensus on this?

Comment: You should have at least one column in your row that runs as the primary key/index, probably auto-increment.This is good practice, as it allows you to edit any other field by referencing the ID number. Otherwise, you would have to directly edit your MySQL database if you wanted to change "Vanilla". (Well, not exactly but you know what I mean, this allows you to uniquely identify rows.)

Comment: @Jason, I have a primary column, but that's not related to this.  I'm just asking what's the preferred method of storing data.

Comment: EAV structure would have you doing both, but that's far more complicated than what it looks like you'll need. In determining what method to use, ask yourself what you would have to do to change it later. If you use INT to store it, you'll have to change your code to add the label if you add a new flavor. For simplicity, I'd use strings since you already have a primary key.

Comment: ok cool. Yea I think strings probably make more sense since it will be easier to work with and I would never have to look up whether a specific number refers to chocolate, vanilla or strawberry.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach with relational databases is to make a new table called `icecream_flavor` or whatver.  Then you can add new flavours at a later date, and your program can offer all the current flavour choices when it asks.  You can store choices by table ID (*ie* an integer).

Comment: What if I have 10 other similar questions.  Do you expect there to be 10 relational tables?  That would seem like I would have to join tables every time I want to retrieve some simple info.  This isn't core functionality, just user profile questions that will be stored in the users table.

Comment: No, in that case, you could provide `things` and `thing_options` (sorry, this isn't very descriptive).  So, ice-cream would be a `thing`, and strawberry is an option for that thing.  The `thing_options` table would provide a unique key `id` and a foreign key `thing_id`.  Then you can have `favourite_things` which is many-to-many between `users` and `thing_options`.  Now you can store arbitrary information about a person's favourite things.  *eg* "raindrops on roses and whiskers on kittens, bright copper kettles and warm woolen mittens..."

Comment: Let me try to put it differently. You have a `users` table with all user info such as `name`, `email`, `password`, etc... Let's say we also want to store a US state. Would you just store the `state` as a string in the `users` table or create a separate table for states and then relate that to the `state` field in the `users` table?

Comment: That's quite a different question.  If it was only US states, I would probably store it with its common abbreviation, but I would use that as the key into a table of full state names.  That would prevent invalid states being stored.  I'm a little conflicted in giving this advice.  I hate it when I am forced to enter a US state online, because I live in New Zealand where there is no concept of a 'state' in our addresses.

Answer (score 1):

If paddy answer isn't an option then you should store the values as ENUM.

While ENUM is pretty equivalent to TINYINT(1).
ENUM is only the answer if the values you let the user choose are already pre-fixed, otherwise you would have to edit the table. But if you use ENUM MySQL has the engine optimized while inserting, and selecting from ENUMs. It's the obvious choice, for example (Male\Female).

Otherwise the answer to your question is TINYINYT(1), which is fastest then both CHAR and INT(1).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a constant set of values and you're not going to relate that values with another data in your database (information related to each type of ice-cream) you can use MySQL's special field type called [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)

Comment: I didn't know about ENUM. Is ENUM much faster than CHAR or VARCHAR?  The reason I ask is that if I add another option in the UI, I would have to add it in the ENUM field it seems like, whereas with CHAR or VARCHAR, I would not.

Comment: @zen you are right. anyway ENUM is much faster then CAHR or VARCHAR are because MySQL doesn't actually store the text value in the field but just numeric values presenting each one, ex. 1 for vanilla, 2 for Chocolate and etc. i think that updating one field would't cause many problems

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you keep the primary index as an int. The simplest reason for doing this is for what you don't currently know and to allow your data model to evolve.

Assuming your example, if you go with the actual word, and in six months you decide to also put in a size - single scoop, double scoop etc, you suddenly have a problem as your primary key that you thought was unique suddenly has multiple entries for each flavour. If on the other hand you go with a numeric format, you can easily have as many variants of Vanilla as you like and everything is happy.

In this case, I would also suggest keeping the actual primary key as a key and nothing more. Add in another column that then has the flavour, or create a lookup table that will store the actual properties of each item. If you keep a numeric format, but have ID 1 as Vanilla, you basically run into the same problem as before, keep the ID as the ID and your details seperate.

To keep data about your items, you can use something like this:

```
Master Table
ID     Name
1      Ice Cream

Properties Table
ID     Type
1      Flavour
2      Size

Property Table
ID     PropID    Detail
1      1         Vanilla
2      1         Strawberry
3      2         Single Scoop
4      2         Double Scoop

MasterToProperty
MasterID     Property    PropID
1            1           1
1            2           4
```

This basically gives you an unlimited number of options, and adding any thing you want (an entry for choc chips for example) is simply a matter of adding a few rows of data, not table changes.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but you're looking at this as an "ice cream website". The question I posted is probably a bad one, but imagine a user profile page with 10 multiple choice questions. They're not the core functionality of the website and likely will never have more than a few options to select from.

Comment: @zen With the simple data model I gave you, you can pretty much do ANYTHING you like, not just ice creams :)

Answer (score 0):

If each user is identifiable by some unique key (say an email address) then you may find you do not need a numerical id.

Keeping the flavour as a flavour when YOU control the option (so you dont get Vanilla, vanilla vanila and so on) suggests to me that you store the real value (Vanilla).

This avoids a join and makes your database data meaningful when you browse it.

You can add an index to the flavour column of the database, so you can "show all users who prefer Vanilla" very cheaply.

(If you potentially have infinite options to store, then maybe you should be investigating using a nosql databases)

Comment: This is basically what I was thinking. Store the data as a string so that I don't have to do a join every time I want to retrieve a simple value. The number of options is also unlikely to change which is why having a separate table for each question seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your database like this:

```
Questions
id, question_text

ex. (1, "What is your favorite ice cream?")

Options
id, question_id, option_text

ex. (1, 1, "Vanilla")

Responses
id, user_id, question_id, option_id

ex. (1, 421, 1, 1)
```

You should also throw some `created` and `modified` fields into each table for keeping track of changes.